# Understanding the Crash Log

Tags: ios

I am an Android Developer and trying some dummy for the iOS development.

I am trying a tutorial for [AMSlideMenu](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) and it was working well at a certain point of development.
I followed the complete tutorial and it worked well. After sometime while I was experimenting some other functionality the code breaked. 
I undo and reverted back the changes but something still looks wrong.

below is the crash log, but i cant understand what went wrong

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdf93f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b6e9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010c7bd43b -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   Pranshu1                            0x000000010b1a0d4f -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController setup] + 1071
    4   Pranshu1                            0x000000010b19dc63 -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController viewDidLoad] + 419
    5   Pranshu1                            0x000000010b19d1b6 -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 54
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c7bb190 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c7e95db -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 44
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c7e9b25 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c7e9c24 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 92
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c7ea9f7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c7eb4b7 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c92f399 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c70f199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c521f98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c516bbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c516a2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c484ade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c485bea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010c69467d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c695368 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2642
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010c693d22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001114912a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd2eabc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd24805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd245c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd23a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010c693799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010c696550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    29  Pranshu1                            0x000000010b1ad003 main + 115
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e822145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What message was printed out just before this? There's usually a crucial piece of information about the exception name/reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up from the top (0) entry the last of your methods is: `Pranshu1` so you need to look there.

The last method is: `-[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`
so it looks like you are performing a Segue, check the identifier.

Before that is the method `AMSlideMenuMainViewController` so it looks like you are probably using the 3rd party code `AMSlideMenu`, check for correct usage.

Here is how to catch the exceptions at the point of the error:

To see the actual statement that is causing the error add an exception breakpoint:

1. From the Main Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint.
2. Right-click the breakpoint and set the exception to Objective-C.
3. Add an action: "po $arg1".

Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

Creating the breakpoint example:
[image]